# return first value from setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a large setTimeout function that generates dynamic variable that change every second. With other functions that I have, I want to attain a variable at the time that I call the setTimeout function, because I want to use it for another function that isn't contained within it. So essentially, I want the first value that I call and I don't want to disturb the function from running.

How would I go about in doing this?

Basically:

```
function schedule() {
  <<changingvalue is here>>
  setTimeout(function () { schedule() }, 1000);
}

console.log(<<changingvalue at a particular instance>>);
```

Comment: Save "changingvalue at a particular instance" in another variable.

Comment: IMHO the best way is a promise because you have to wait about 1 second for the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a promise to return the value after the first `setTimeout` finishes

```js
let a = 1234;

function schedule() {
  ++a;
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(function () { schedule(); r(a); }, 1000));
}

(async () => {
  console.log(await schedule());
})();
```

or simply return the value

```js
let a = 1234;

function schedule() {
  ++a;
  setTimeout(function () { schedule(); }, 1000);
  return a;
}

console.log(schedule());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#field_declarations). Initialise the count in the constructor then call the `loop` method which updates the count, and then calls itself again once a second.

You can then create a new instance from the class and then call `getCount` from your other functions whenever you need to.

In this example I have an interval that calls the `getCount` once every three seconds, so you'll see output: 3, 6, 9 etc.

```js
class Timeout {

  constructor() {
    this.count = 0;
    this.loop();
  }
  
  getCount() {
    return this.count;
  }
  
  loop() {
    this.count = this.count + 1;
    setTimeout(this.loop.bind(this), 1000);
  }

}

const timeout = new Timeout();

setInterval(() => {
  console.log(timeout.getCount());
}, 3000);
```